# Cost of ORDER BY in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I know that the data in a cassandra table is already sorted by the clustering column. So when we use the `ORDER BY` clause, is it safe to assume that no sorting is actually done (while spanning across rows)? Are the results just fetched in the reverse order when `ORDER BY` is used? I would like to know the cost of this operation.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so let's say that I have this table, designed to track customers by the music albums they have purchased:

```
CREATE TABLE customers_by_album (
  album TEXT,
  band TEXT,
  custno INT,
  customer_name TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (album,custno))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (custno ASC);
```

Once I insert some data and run a `nodetool flush` (forcing it to disk), I'll run the following query, flipping the sort direction:

```
aaron@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT album,token(album),band,custno,customer_name
    FROM customers_by_album
    WHERE album='Moving Pictures'
    ORDER BY custno DESC;
```

As I am querying on the partition key `album`, the `album` value of `Moving Pictures` gets hashed to a token of 7819329704333693835.  Node 10.0.0.5 is responsible for token 7819329704333693835, and the query is sent there.  Assuming a row/key cache miss, Cassandra heads to the directory `stackoverflow/customers_by_album-e2820d00d88311e9b9dc413ae9a4e561/` and locates the appropriate SSTable file(s).

Inside the file, it finds the partition and starts reading sequentially:

[image]

Once the requested data is read, it now has to reverse the sort direction of the data it just read, returning these results:

```
 album           | system.token(album) | band | custno | customer_name
-----------------+---------------------+------+--------|---------------
 Moving Pictures | 7819329704333693835 | Rush |     14 | Mitch
 Moving Pictures | 7819329704333693835 | Rush |     13 | Jeff
 Moving Pictures | 7819329704333693835 | Rush |     12 | Ted
 Moving Pictures | 7819329704333693835 | Rush |     11 | Aaron

(4 rows)
```

The cost associated with the flip in sort direction may seem miniscule.  When I run that query with `TRACING ON`, I get a result in **20.217ms**.  When I specify `ORDER BY custno ASC` (ORDER BY with a sort direction that matches the on-disk sort order) I get a result in **10.98ms**.

Now imagine storing tens of thousands of rows in your partition, pulling back a few dozen columns, and *then* flipping the sort direction.  I've worked with app teams who have queries for large result sets that time-out when whey flip the sort direction.  So the "cost" of changing the sort direction is definitely proportional to the number of rows/columns read.

Answer (score 1):

When you retrieve the data with `ORDER BY` that is the same as order specified in your table definition, then Cassandra just "jumps" into the begin of the region, and read data linearly. When you have `ORDER BY` in the reverse direction, it's slightly more expensive, but not critical. But be careful, that if you reverse order for first clustering column, then the order for the rest of the clustering columns will change.

Comment: Why is it more expensive when we have `ORDER BY` in the reverse direction though? What is happening under the hood?

Comment: Index have physical ordering..  for more read how index work in general...